# Odoo 12: KeyError: 'ir.values'

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I m trying to create a new contact in odoo application but it shows me this error :

```
KeyError: 'ir.values'
```

The issue is related with this funtion.

```
 class ResPartner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

def _default_credit_limit(self):
    return self.env['ir.values'].get_default('account.config.settings', 'credit_limit')
```

**I don't understand the problem**

**Can you please help me**

Comment: which version of Odoo you are using?

Comment: thanks fo your response. I m using odoo 12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> KeyError: 'ir.values'

If you run `self.env['ir.values']` on Odoo 12, you will get the above error because the `ir.values` Model does not exist in Odoo 12.

The `ir.values` Model was removed and replaced with `ir.default`. For example:

```
self.env['ir.default'].get('sale.order', 'sale_order_template_id')
```

You can see the relevant file [in the Odoo core code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_default.py) or [the commit where most of that  Model was added](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/60d9f6fef9e15c96cb710a17318a56c1cc1c33dc#diff-9af8b31d921dcccb7bcf230271fd3ef4).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this setting even exists anymore? I don't know for sure, but couldn't find it, i'm aware in Odoo 8 it existed. Beside the fact, that i don't think it exists anymore: `account.config.settings` don't exist for 100% sure, because the settings model was refactored into `res.config.settings`.

Actually the partner field `credit_limit` is gone, too. So if you want to use it and have a default outside the code, use `ir.default` for your desired behaviour.

Comment: hey @CZoellner thanks for your response. I can't use ['ir.default'] object cause it has no attribute 'get_default'

Comment: You obviously have to look into the model yourself. ;-) You need to set a default value by yourself, too, it's not existing for `credit_limit`